# Testing graphql-upload with MockedProvider

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

How can GraphQL uploads be mocked with `MockedProvider` using the `apollo-upload-client` package?

Given the following mutation:

```
mutation import($file: Upload!) {
  import(file: $file) {
    success
  }
}
```

And the following mock:

```
export const importSuccessFile = new File(
  [’test'],
  ’test.txt',
  { type: 'text/plain' }
)

export const importMock = {
  request: {
    query: ImportDocument,
    variables: {
      file: importSuccessFile,
    },
  },
  result: {
    data: {
      import: {
        success: true,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

The response will never return, warning: `No more mocked responses for the query`.

I understand the `file` will be processed by Apollo and will be a different object from the file uploaded, which is the issue. I’m unsure of how to supply this so the equality check matches.

Comment: You cannot use js constructed file as an input, as it's not a valid input, you must use file-api, something like input onFileChange event, or some kind of FilePicker.js API

Comment: If you mean triggering the `import` mutation in an `onChange` event for an input field, then I’ve done this and shown in the answer below. Doesn’t sound like the library you suggested is needed - I don’t want to upload to another server, I have the upload working via GraphQL?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, overriding the mutation hook function in the component by passing it as a prop is a workaround:

```
export interface ImportDialogProps {
  import?: ReturnType<typeof useImportMutation>[0]
}

export const ImportDialog: React.FC<ImportDialogProps> = ({
  import: importOverride,
  ...rest
}) => {
const [importDefault] = useImportMutation()

const import = importOverride ?? importDefault

// do something with mutation...
}
```